# Flutter: How To Set a Background Timer

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to have a background timer going on while the user is out of the app, and the app is swiped out of the app history.

Comment: Hi Sameer, Stackoverflow works best when you try stuff that doesn't work, post it here, and then we comment on it

Comment: Refer this https://navinkumar0118.medium.com/flutter-countdown-timer-works-in-background-f87488b0ba4c

Answer (score 1):

You should use the flutter package named as [background_fetch](https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch/example). This will resolve your solution.

ALTERNATIVE ANS TO background_fetch :

If your requirement is just to put the timer in background. This should be the simple way. Just try below code:

```
Timer timer;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 15), (Timer t){
  setState(() {});
});
}

@override
void dispose() {
  timer?.cancel();
  super.dispose();
}
```

**SOLUTION 2:**

If you want to complete several tasks in background then I should recommend go with the link below of medium article https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124.

**OTHER SOLUTION**:

If you are using flutter_bloc than go with this solution https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-timer-with-flutter-bloc-a464e8332ceb.

Comment: Is there another way I don't understand how to use that package

Comment: @Sameer You could use https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager which is an alternative to background_fetch

Comment: I have edited the answer and the simpler way to have background timer is code written above. Also the link provided by the @BLKKKBVSIK is an good answer. You can do in any way.

Comment: Once the user swipes out of the app there is no timer, thats the problem I have

Comment: I want to have the timer running even when the user is not in the app

Answer (score 0):

This is already complicated because Dart is single-threaded.

The problem is that you want to have the timer run even "while the user is out of the app, and the app is swiped out of the app history."

Isolates are a potential solution. But the problem with isolates is that while it will run when your app is in the background, the OS will kill it when the app is killed itself. I would recommend reading on isolates [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/concurrency)

Another solution would be using [android_alarm_manager_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager_plus) for accessing the Android AlarmManager service and running Dart code in the background when alarms fire. But there is no such package on iOS.

What I did for a similar problem was listen to flutter's lifecycle hooks
and use *shared_prefernces* to save timer values: When the app is in the foreground and the timer is started, listen on Flutter's lifecycle hooks for state change. As soon as the app is removed from the f/g (killed or moved to b/g), save the timer value in *shared_preferences*. When the app is in the f/g again, check for active timers from *shared_prefences*, calculate the difference between the saved timer and `DateTime.now()` and resume the timer from the adjusted offset.

Helps you cover the case when the app is completely killed and you want the timer to keep running.